# has_many :through Survey attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a Survey which can participated by Participants:

Survey has_many: Questions which has_many: Answers

A Participant should be able to add his Voting to each of the Answers (values are [-1,0,1] )

One question looks like this:

```
Question 1
 - Answer1 -> Please vote -1 / 0 / 1 (Checkbox field)
 - Answer2 -> Please vote -1 / 0 / 1 (Checkbox field)
 - Answer3 -> Please vote -1 / 0 / 1 (Checkbox field)
 - Participant Comment               (Text Field)
 - Participant Average               (Rating Field)
```

How do I save a voting correctly? I wanna keep the `participant_id, answer_id AND voting_value` get saved.

ADDED for explanation:

(User will get answer)

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :surveys
  has_many :participants
end

Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions
end

Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers
end

Answers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :votings
end

Voting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :participant
  attr_accessible :value
end

Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votings
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Please post your models with relationship definitions.

Comment: This person's models may shed some light to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612855/redirecting-to-new-page-with-already-existing-records-after-user-login-for-authe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `participant` and `user` models need to be merged into one because isn't `participant` an `user`?  I do not see why `Participant` model would be necessary here.

Say, we merge `User` and `Participant` into just `User`, the association between `User` and `Voting` would then be:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :surveys
  has_many :votings 
end

Voting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :value
end
```

Now from your first code block:

```
Question 1
 - Answer1 -> Please vote -1 / 0 / 1 (Checkbox field)
 - Answer2 -> Please vote -1 / 0 / 1 (Checkbox field)
 - Answer3 -> Please vote -1 / 0 / 1 (Checkbox field)
 - Participant Comment               (Text Field)
 - Participant Average               (Rating Field)
```

Isn't voting done on answers by users?  In that case do we need `user has_many :votings` relationship?  I think the association spoken out would be `User` takes many `Surveys`, `Survey` has many `Questions`, `Question` has many `Answers` and Answer has many `Votings`.  Each of which votings may be checked.  So for this I don't think a direct association between `User` and `Voting` is the solution.

Following is updated `User`, `Answer` and `Voting` models with updates association:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :surveys
end

Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :votings
end

Voting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  attr_accessible :value
end
```

Finally there a couple of other minor typos like `Answers < ActiveRecord::Base` where class `Answer` should not be plural.

The second problem is you have `User` `has_and_belongs_to_many` `Surveys`.  You are defining `many to many` relationship between `User` and `Survey` so you need to define the same in your `Survey` model as well:

```
Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :questions
end
```

With all those updates your models along with relationships would look as follows (Note: I've also added `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in models so that when your form submits you don't need to manually build each of the associated objects):

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :surveys
end

Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :questions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

Answers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :votings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :votings
end

Voting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  attr_accessible :value     
end
```

With the above model relationshp you could build your `SurveysController`'s `new` and `create` action would look similar to follows:

```
# app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb
class SurveysController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @survey = current_user.surveys.build do
    @question = @survey.questions.build
    @answer = @question.answers.build

    # Build three different votings for answer with default value.
    [-1, 0, 1].each do |voting_value| 
      @answer.votings.build(value: voting_value)
    end
  end


  def create
    @survey = current_user.surveys.build(params[:survey])
    @survey.save 
    # Of course you would check if save succeeded or failed and take action accordingly.
  end
end
```

Also, I'd recommended you to look into `has_many...through` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` for defining `many to many` relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation and sharing your thoughts. I definitly can partially implement some of your code "chunks". In my opinion I have to use the participant model. There is some more logic in the background (users can attend on a survey and hand out random codes to participants to let them attend anonymously. Participants have no rights and User should pay, etc... I think I can't exclude the participant.